# html5 geolocation search within radius

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html, geolocation

I can use [html5 API](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) in conjunction with Javascript to get the longitude and latitude of user. I want to take this one more further step, I want to make a search query -something like Tinder the mobile app-- to run and search for other users within a certain radius, say like run a search from my registered location to search within an 800 meters around my position for other registered locations of other users.

Any idea how to make that ? I'm a novice in php, ajax and javascript, please try to explain in simple terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the **haversine formulae**

Check [this webpage](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) for a Javascript application of it